# How do I solve the following design in the MVVM paradigm? (newb)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm still starting out with MVVM and read through all the MSDN Prism examples but I'd nonetheless like some guidance with the following design problem which I feel will help me latch onto the Prism concepts and reinforce what I just learnt

I have a multi-window application - each window has a filter drop down control. The value of this filter control will affect the display of other controls within that same window, eg grids, charts etc.

Certain interactions (eg double clicking a row on a grid) will spawn another window which will have its own separate filter control, which will similarly affect the display of other controls only within that window

How do I implement this behavior of the filter driving the display of other user controls it has no idea of and have it restrict its behavior to only the window hosting it? How do I keep these interactions loosely coupled?

I'm thinking I need to use the EventAggregator and for the filter control to publish an update event when the selection changes? Am I thinking about this the right way? Would each window need a separate EventAggregator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking about this the right way.  The EventAggregator is a good tool for what you're doing.  You'll need to have the EventAggregator on every window you plan to raise an event from.  You can inject the EA into your constructor or use the ServiceLocator.  Here are 2 examples:

```
// Ctor injection
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public ViewModelBase(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}

// Service Locator
 ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<YourEvent>().Publish();
```

Now, you'll need to create a CompositePresentationEvent for the EA to publish.  You can minimize the number of these that get created by including a payload in the CPE.  Something like this:

```
public class NavigationSelectedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<NavigationEnum.Destination>{}
```

So now you're ready to publish the event:

```
 _eventAggregator.GetEvent<NavigationSelectedEvent>().Publish(NavigationEnum.Destination.Home);
```

And then subscribe to it - using an optional filter on the payload so you're not wasting resources:

```
this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<NavigationSelectedEvent>().Subscribe(HandleNavigationEvent, ThreadOption.UIThread, false, i => i == NavigationEnum.Destination.Home);
```

Comment: Ahh excellent - it's the filter on the payload I'm looking for! 
Great thanks for the guidance, that's actually exactly the way I had in mind good to see I'm on the right track phew! :)

Comment: One question I have - how would I set what window the current ViewModel is part of in an MVVM-oriented manner? I have the impression that VMs don't know about the views (and hence windows) that bind them, therefore how would I tell the VMs of my controls which window they're part of?

Comment: @blue18hutthutt...You're right, the VMs shouldn't know about the views.  You'll need to use create Regions in the views/xaml and use the RegionManager to load them.

Comment: Problem is, what if the windows are the same type, but vary by parameter when created - wouldn't you then have multiple windows with the same region names? In which case one region name would apply to multiple regions across windows rather than the instance it originated from?

Comment: @blue18hutthutt...Read this and focus on the RegionManager and ModuleManager - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should publish the filter notification using the `EventAggregator`, that is the best way to do it from my experience. You should be using only one `EventAggregator` to serve as a hub between all the subscribing objects.

Something like:

```
MyNotificationChangedArgs args = new MyNotificationChangedArgs();
args.Payload = GetThePayload(someParameters);
myEventAggregator.GetEvent<NotificationFilterChangedEvent>().Publish(args);
```

Another thing that really helps is to dependency-inject the `EventAggregator`, for instance via `Unity`. This way all of your controls can simply access the common `EventAggregator` by calling on the `UnityContainer.Resolve` method:

```
var myEventAggregator = myUnityContainer.Resolve<MyEventAggregator>();
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need a separate EventAggregator for each new window? Since each window has a separate instance of the filter control, which should only apply to the controls within that window, wouldn't I need different EventAggregators so as not to have controls from all windows register the same filter? Or would it make more sense to include the window ID in the event payload?

Comment: @blue18hutthutt: you should use just one `EventAggregator`, otherwise you'll get an interesting surprise, LOL...

Comment: why what will happen? :)
Would the best thing to do then be to include some sort of window ID within the payload of the event?

Comment: I believe the last time I did that, my subscribing objects suddenly stopped receiving published events -- they were subscribing to the wrong `EventAggregator` instances... I found it's best to think of each `EventAggregator` as hubs that broadcast messages to listeners exclusive to themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I think the best thing would be to publish the window ID and filter on the presentation event (as mentioned in the other answer)

Answer (score 1):

Every View has access to the Model through the ViewModel. Model your filters. Then the Views bind to ViewModel representations that use the filters. Your Views don't have to know about each other, they just have to bind to the Model.